# How to override tapestry AlertManager

Tags: java, tapestry

I have created extended alert manager:
interface

```
public interface AlertManagerExt extends AlertManager {
    void successCode(String messageCode, Object... args);
    void infoCode(String messageCode, Object... args);
    void warnCode(String messageCode, Object... args);
    void errorCode(String messageCode, Object... args);
}
```

and implementation

```
public class AlertManagerExtImpl extends AlertManagerImpl implements AlertManagerExt {

    private final Messages messages;

    public AlertManagerExtImpl(ApplicationStateManager asm, Request request, AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer,
            PerthreadManager perThreadManager, Messages messages) {
        super(asm, request, ajaxResponseRenderer, perThreadManager);
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public void successCode(String messageCode, Object... args) {
        success(getMessage(messageCode, args));
    }

    @Override
    public void infoCode(String messageCode, Object... args) {
        info(getMessage(messageCode, args));
    }

    @Override
    public void warnCode(String messageCode, Object... args) {
        warn(getMessage(messageCode, args));
    }

    @Override
    public void errorCode(String messageCode, Object... args) {
        error(getMessage(messageCode, args));
    }

    protected String getMessage(String code, Object... args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            return messages.format(code, args);
        }
        return messages.get(code);
    }
}
```

When I tried to bind it via binder:

```
binder.bind(AlertManagerExt.class, AlertManagerExtImpl.class);
```

I got exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Service interface org.apache.tapestry5.alerts.AlertManager is matched by 2 services: AlertManager, AlertManagerExtImpl.  Automatic dependency resolution requires that exactly one service implement the interface.
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getServiceByTypeAlone(RegistryImpl.java:789)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getServiceByTypeAndMarkers(RegistryImpl.java:797)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getService(RegistryImpl.java:755)
```

I know I can copy-and-paste all methods from AlertManager and do not extend it. But may be there is better way?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Tapestry IoC tries to find all services that implement an interface when you try to `@Inject` it by interface type only. Your new `AlertManagerExt` also implements the `AlertManager` hence the ambiguity.

This is usually resolved by explicitly specifying service ID or marker annotation, but this won't work for your case as tapestry's core code already `@Inject`ing `AlertManager` by interface only.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but I ran into a similar exception trying to override an internal Tapestry service implementation, (GoogleClosureMinimizerOptionsProvider in my case), and I managed to solve it using by contributing to ServiceOverride.class using the annotation.
For example in my Tapestry ApplicationModule, I have this:

```
@Contribute(ServiceOverride.class)
public static void contributeServiceOverride(MappedConfiguration<Class<? extends GoogleClosureMinimizerOptionsProvider>,Object<? super GoogleClosureMinimizerOptionsProvider>> configuration) {
  configuration.addInstance(GoogleClosureMinimizerOptionsProvider.class, CustomGCMCompilerOptions.class)
```

I believe this could work in your case as well:

```
@Contribute(ServiceOverride.class)
public static void contributeServiceOverride(MappedConfiguration<Class<? extends AlertManager,Object<? super AlertManager> configuration) {
configuration.addInstance(AlertManager.class, AlertManagerExtImpl.class)
```

Quick ref to the `ServiceOverride` interface Tapestry5 [APIDocs](https://people.apache.org/%7Ehlship/t5api/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/services/ServiceOverride.html):

> @UsesMappedConfiguration(key=java.lang.Class.class,
> value=java.lang.Object.class)
> public interface ServiceOverride
>
> Used to override built in services. Simply contribute a mapping from a type >to an instance of that type. Anywhere that exact type is injected, without >specifying markers or other annotations, the contributed instance will be >injected, even if there is already a service that implements the interface.
>
> In fact, this is not limited to overriding services; any object that can be >injected based solely on type can be contributed.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this in a few ways, depending on what you really need. I invite you to read the [documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/defining-tapestry-ioc-services.html) and the [IoC cookbook](https://tapestry.apache.org/ioc-cookbook-basic-services-and-injection.html).

Understanding the Inversion of Control configuration is important because it's a very powerful module.

Comment: What I need is pretty obvious from source of service implementation. I'm quite familiar with T5 IoC and the reason I posted my question in stackoverflow is that my case is not covered in documentation.